# Cannot implicitly convert from BaseClass<int> to DerivedClass

Tags: c#

I cannot implicitly convert from a `BaseClass<int>` to its `DerivedClass`. I have the following code:

```
class BaseClass<T>
{
}

class DerivedClass : BaseClass<int>
{
    int blah;
}
```

However a method `foo()` that returns a `BaseClass<int>` object cannot make the following works:

```
DerivedClass tmp = foo();
```

---

Update: the casting `DerivedClass tmp = (DerivedClass)foo();` also didn't work.

Comment: That's right. What's the question?

Comment: You can only do it the other way round...

Answer (score 3):

That is due to the rules of inheritance and upcasting.

let's say we've got class A, and B which is derived from it:

```
Class A{
}

Class B : A{
}
```

since B **is an** A, then you can do 
`A a = new B()`;

that is correct, you just look at that B through 'eyes of' A. this is called **Upcasting.**

yet, A **is not** a B, so doing that 
`B b = new A()`

is incorrect, b cannot be instantiated as it's parent class.

the way to do this would be like

```
B b = (B)a;
```

which is called RTTI or **Downcasting** . which is usually not recommended in OOP.

hope that helps.

EDIT :

The downcasting example I gave throws an error since that "a" variable, is really an A.

safe Downcasting be like this:

```
A a = new B(); \\a is a B looking through A, upcasting.
B b = (B)a; \\ this is downcasting, since now I want to use a with his B identity
```

Comment: The answer is good, but you may consider to make the format better too... ;)

Comment: And thanks for your detailed explanation and patience... Maybe I should review OOP systematically, but I really want this to work.

Comment: do look at it again now.

Answer (score 1):

This is really really basic c# knowledge (or any other object oriented language I know):

If you have a `class B : A` you may assign the derived class to a variable of the base type like `A myA = new B()`, but you cannot do it the other way round like `B myB = new A()`.

Imagine this:

```
public class Animal
{}

public class Gnu : Animal
{}

public class Lion : Animal
{}
```

So you want to do something like that:

```
Animal lion = new Lion(); // that's ok
Gnu gnu = lion; // that will hurt!
```

Don't do this to gnus!

Answer (score 1):

In object oriented programming, classes follow the so-called "is a" logic.  A derived class "is a" base class, in order for the inheritance to make sense.

Say you have a `Person` class and an `Employee` class as follows

```
class Person {
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int Age { get; set; }
}

class Employee : Person {
    public decimal Salary { get; set; }
    public string JobTitle { get; set; }
}
```

Now suppose you make an instance of `Person` in your code, and try to assign it to `Employee`.  C# can't make sense of this because the object you created doesn't have a `Salary` or `JobTitle`.

```
var person = new Person();
var employee = (Employee) person; // heh?
```

On the other hand, creating an instance of `Employee` and casting it to a `Person` **does** make sense because an `Employee` "is a" `Person` but a `Person` is not an `Employee`.